# What does "order" mean in "to the order of"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I read a sentence in "The Hindu" which was:

> It is estimated that since the barter trade commenced along two routes across the LoC in October 2008, employment to the order of more than 1.6 lacs days had been created.

I don't know what "to the order of" means here.

Could the word "order" mean degree here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, the writer intended or more correctly would have used "on the order of". This is an expression derived from the mathematical term "order of magnitude" meaning "by the same factor of ten".

"On the order of" is often used less precisely to just mean "approximately".

Comment: @ReedWade- could the word "order" mean degree here?

Comment: yes, I think that would be consistent

Answer (score -1):

Basically "To the order of "is used for bank cheques which means :"on demand of " or let's say "this cheque is for the sake of( a person) .

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/144774)

Comment: "*to the order of*" has more than one use, and the use in the example in the question doesn't have the meaning of a written direction to pay money to someone. Rather, it has the meaning given in Reed Wade's answer.